# Create zoom function on button click for iframe (same domain)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an iframe whose src link will be on the same domain as the parent site. I want to build a zoom feature so that the user can click a "+" or "-" button and the contents within the iframe either shrinks or grows, depending on the button click.

I know that iframes are tricky to work with, and I'm struggling to find a working example of what I would like to do. I'm wondering if this is even possible. Any examples or a quick demo would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please let us know why you are using an iframe. The only reason I can think of is loading a document and plugin.. and in this case zooming may not work as described.

Comment: You are correct, I'm using it to display a document. The document is an image with text mapped out onto it. I was hoping there was a way to collectively zoom in on the contents of the iframe, the way you can zoom a browser window to increase text/image size.

Comment: I'd suggest to implement this using a div (fixed size and overflow auto) instead of an iframe and scale the content using css. Have a look at transform: "scale(value)"

Answer (score 0):

you are going to need to do a couple things.

First, assuming the +/- are outside the iframe you will need a postmessage and messagereceive listener on the iframe so that the parent can post data to the iframe

you will then need to have a way of scaling up the content of the iframe (there are a ton of ways to do this from using JS and math to using REM/EM as your units in CSS and then changing a base value on html)